# Cannot extract single row when parsing web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I try to parse row containing player's values from this website http://tennisabstract.com/reports/atp_elo_ratings.html

So it should look like single "tr" attribute with values

Code:

```
url = "http://tennisabstract.com/reports/atp_elo_ratings.html"
player_name = "Novak"

page = requests.get(url)
parser = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
rows = parser.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    try:
        if player_name in row.a["href"]:
            print(row)
            break
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

When I print row in for loop, outside of try-except block, it works just fine, but when I use print(row) in try block the output is all rows instead of one.

I don't understand why this happens and documentation didn't help me.

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and inside the `try-except` it works fine but outside, I'm getting an error `    `if player_name in row.a["href"]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and this is because `row.a` returns `None` may I ask if you get this issue also? thanks

Comment: Yes, not all rows have 'a' attributes in them. I tried just print(row) outside of try except block and it showed 301 rows separately, fine to me. But in try except block it somehow compress all values into one row.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply, it doesn’t. The *long string* you are seeing in your output is actually the 4th element in your `rows` list. You can confirm so yourself:

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        if player_name in row.a["href"]:
            print(row)
            print(row == rows[3]) # single row equal to the fourth element in your 'rows' list
            break
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Since you immediately break once you print one such `row` which has your player name, you don't see other rows and it seems like this one big row is made up of 301 other such rows, but that is not the case. You might need change how you find the elements in your parsed HTML to break up the results.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get why is this so? It should work as fourth tr element is the row I am looking for, consisted of player's name and his values, no more. If choosing another way for retrieving this data how should I do it, via td tags?

Comment: I believe that would be the way to go in addition to `th` tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why this method doesn't work. Instead I find another way of retrieving this data iterating via 'a' tags and then calling its parent.

```
links = parser.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if player_name in link['href']:
        row = link.parent.parent
        print("Value:", row)
        break
```

Output:
Value: 1[Novak Djokovic](http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/player.cgi?p=NovakDjokovic)33.52228.02111.92092.72013.92170.02160.32120.92016 Miami F28.82469.6